# facebook is not allowing some urls in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-ios-sdk

```
some urls are not allowing in facebook post like this type of urls
```

**http://c801459.r59.cf2.rackcdn.com/PYCVfhCn_large_small.jpg**
   
[image]

```
i am trying to see the response in
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

```
here i am getting the error show in below screen shot
```

[image]